# Vuex вовзращает одинаковые state по-разному

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Проблема в том, что с 2-мя store с абсолютно одинаковым кодом(изменены только названия) Vuex возвращает данные по-разному.
В первом случае(Category) он возвращает массив с 0 элементами, а во втором (Channels) возвращает пустой объект. Actions выполняются последовательно в одном методе

CategoriesStore.js

```
state: {
        categories: {},
        category: {}
    },
    getters: {
        categories: (state) => {
            return state.categories;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setCategories(state, categories) {
            Vue.set(state, 'categories', categories)
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getCategories(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get('/api/category')
                    .then((response) => {
                        context.commit('setCategories', response.data.data);
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch((response) => reject(response));
            });
        }
    }
```

ChannelsStore.js

```
store: {
        channels: [],
        channel: {}
},
getters: {
        channels: (state) => {
            return state.channels;
        },
},
mutations: {
        setChannels: (state, channels) => {
            Vue.set(state, 'channels', channels);
        },
},
actions: {
        getChannels: (context) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get('/api/channels')
                    .then((response) => {
                        context.commit('setChannels', response.data.data);
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch((response) => {
                        reject(response);
                    })
            });
        },
},
```

Vue Devtools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вы и объявили объекты по-разному. В первом случае у вас categories - это объект {}, а во втором случае channels - это массив []. Массивы и объекты работают по-разному.

Comment: Не дописал немного вопрос, суть в том, что значения не имеет, что это будет: объект или массив или строка или т.д Суть в том, что девтулза не знает что находится внутри channels, но знает, что находится внутри categories

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что в CategoriesStore.js есть свойство state, а в ChannelsStore.js вместо него используется свойство store.

Comment: Убить бы мою невнимательность! Спасибо вам, Виктор! Пора выбираться из группы людей, которых нужно тыкать носом в их собственный код. Оставьте, пожалуйста, ответ, чтобы я мог его плюсануть